# R: How to remove duplicated entry across columns within each row

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates

I have a dataframe that looks like the following. Within each row, I would like to remove entries in X1:n that are duplicate entries.

```
> df <- data.frame(ID = c("100", "101", "102"),
+                  X1 = c("C23.2", "C23.2", "A79.1"), 
+                  X2 = c("C23.2", NA, "A79.1"),
+                  X3 = c("A19.2", NA, "A79.1"))
```

The output would look something like this

```
   ID    X2    X3    X4
1 100 C23.2 A19.2  <NA>
2 101 C23.2  <NA>  <NA>
3 102 A79.1  <NA>  <NA>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `pmap_dfr` from `purrr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df %>%
  pmap_dfr(., ~c(...) %>% replace(., duplicated(.), NA)) %>%
  bind_cols(select(df), .)
```

Output:

```
   ID    X1   X2    X3
1 100 C23.2 <NA> A19.2
2 101 C23.2 <NA>  <NA>
3 102 A79.1 <NA>  <NA>
```

Answer (score 3):

In `base R`, use `apply` to loop over the rows, extract the non-duplicated elements and readjust the `length`

```
df[-1] <- t(apply(df[-1], 1, \(x) `length<-`(x[!duplicated(x)], length(x))))
```

-output

```
> df
   ID    X1    X2   X3
1 100 C23.2 A19.2 <NA>
2 101 C23.2  <NA> <NA>
3 102 A79.1  <NA> <NA>
```

Comment: Could you clarify why the function inside `apply()` does not return `length(x)` as a result? After all `\`length<-\`(x, value)` is equivalent to doing `length(x) <- value`. And if this is the last line of a function, the function will return the length of `x`.

Comment: @mastropi it is just that we are subsetting the elements `x[!duplicated(x)]` to return only unique values which could reduce the length if there are duplicates.  By assigning `length<-`, it appends `NA` at the end of the vector whereever there are less length

Comment: Yes, I had understood what it does. What I still don't understand is why the returned value is not the length of x but the array containing the x values (because of my reasoning written in my previous comment).

Comment: @matropi  It is returning the length of x.  Sorry, I am not sure I understand why you said it is not returning the length of x.  It is updating to length of x by filling with NA at the end

Comment: Well no, the inline function is _not_ returning the length of `x` because, if it were, each row stored into the output `df[-1]` would be `3 3 3`. Instead what is stored in `df[-1]` are the (modified) `x` _values_, not the _length_ of each data frame row (i.e. _not_ the length of `x`).

Comment: @mastropi length of each row is `ncol(df)-1` because we are looping over a selected number of columns (excluding the first column).  Not sure where is the confusion

Comment: I think you don't get my point or I cannot make myself clear. So don't worry. Thanks anyway for the nice one-liner solution!

Comment: @mastropi check these cases `apply(df[-1], 1, function(x) length(x)); apply(df[-1], 1, function(x) length(x[!duplicated(x)]));apply(df[-1], 1, function(x) length("length<-"(x[!duplicated(x)], length(x))))`

Comment: The first one is the original length which is 3 per each row which is equal to number of columns -1 (as we are subsetting with only 3 columns as input), second one is the length from subset of x which is less than the first i.e. 2, 2, 1.  and third is the changed length with `"length<-"` which is again 3, 3, 3

Comment: Exactly: each of your examples return integer numbers (the length of something). But the function you wrote returns the _data_ not the length... And my question is why, since in your response to the OP you are returning the `length` of `x` (after assigning the value 3 to it).

Comment: @mastropi that is because `length<-` is a different function than `length` i.e. former is a setter, whereas `length` is a getter

Comment: So, can we generalize and say that whenever a setter is returned, we are actually returning the _data_ whose property is set?

Comment: @mastropi not every function have getter and setter.  There are some like `names` which would `names<-` for setter.  If you are confused by the code.  I would consider using two expressions i.e. `{x1 <- x[!duplicated(x)]; length(x1) <- length(x); x1})`